# Does Oracle 11g2 support cursor for sem_match function?

Tags: oracle, semantics, owl

I was trying to explore the semantic features of Oracle Database by running a semantic related sql on a semantic model I created in Oracle. But I can't make it work, and there are little information about this.

The function of the procedure is simple,  to get the result set from the sparql query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MERGE_PATHWAY_SEM AS 
TYPE c_type IS REF CURSOR;
semCursor c_type;
p1 VARCHAR2(40);
p2 VARCHAR2(40);
interCount INTEGER;

BEGIN
OPEN semCursor FOR
 'SELECT p1, p2, COUNT(g) as interCount
  FROM TABLE (sem_match (
                  "{?p1 <http://example.com/test.owl#relates_to> ?g .  ?p2              <http://example.com/test.owl#relates_to> ?g }",
                      sem_models("pathway"),
                      null,
                      null,
                      null))';

LOOP
FETCH semCursor INTO p1, p2, interCount;
EXIT WHEN semCursor%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p1||','||p2||','||interCount);
END LOOP; 

/*
FOR records IN semCursor LOOP
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test'); 
END LOOP; */
END PROC_MERGE_PATHWAY_SEM;
```

Compiling errors are as follow:

ORA-00972: identifier is too long

ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.PROC_MERGE_PATHWAY_SEM", line 9

ORA-06512: at line 2

I'm not sure if it is caused by sem_match syntax error wrapped by cursor statement, or a bug in Oracle 11g2? Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need the `'` quotes around the select statement?

Comment: If I don't put `'` quotes, it regards the two Sparql query statements as a whole string, which leads to "identifier too long" error.

Comment: Hi Mat, I know I should not put `'` quotes around the select statement, but I made the change according to this page [Thread: SEM_MATCH in Cursor causing error, ORA-22905](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4561450), which can only make my procedure compiled successfully, but run with mentioned errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using double quotes (`"`) in the `sem_match` call, where I think you should be using two single quotes (`''`); which you need because it's already inside single quotes from the `open ... for`.

(I should maybe note that I've never used semantics, but the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28397/sdo_rdf_concepts.htm#CHDJACII) indicate single quotes).

The double quotes are causing the whole string within them to be treated as a literal identifier, hence the error message.

But as Mat commented, you don't need the single quotes around the `select`, so you don't need to escape those in the `sem_match`.

**Updated following comments**: Assuming you do need the whole `select` wrapped in single quotes as the article you linked to suggests, the single quotes that were already inside the command need to be escaped, which in Oracle is done by using two single quotes together (`''`); in the article that looked rather like a double quote (`"`) instead so I can understand your confusion. Based on the code you put in paste bin:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROC_MERGE_PATHWAY_SEM AS 
TYPE c_type IS REF CURSOR;
semCursor c_type;
p1 VARCHAR2(40);
p2 VARCHAR2(40);
interCount INTEGER;

BEGIN
  OPEN semCursor FOR
     'SELECT p1, p2, COUNT(g) as interCount
      FROM TABLE (sem_match (
                      ''{?p1 <http://example.com/test.owl#relates_to> ?g .  ?p2 <http://example.com/test.owl#relates_to> ?g }'',
                          sem_models(''pathway''),
                          null,
                          null,
                          null))';

   LOOP
   FETCH semCursor INTO p1, p2, interCount;
   EXIT WHEN semCursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p1||','||p2||','||interCount); 
   END LOOP; 

 /*
  FOR records IN semCursor LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test'); 
  END LOOP; */
END PROC_MERGE_PATHWAY_SEM;
```

Each of the `"` you had in your query in the original question is replaced by **two** single quotes, so `sem_models("pathway")` becomes `sem_models(''pathway'')`.

Comment: If I remove the `'` quotes around `select`, there will be "identifier too long" error. If I also change the `"` quotes in the `sem_match` function to `'`, the major error is "ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item".

Comment: You had the ORA-00972 already, so removing the `'` around the `select`  doesn't seem to change anything. The `"` are just wrong, you only use them when really necessary around identifiers (when case-sensitive). So your real problem is the ORA-22905, the other error was just masking that...

Comment: OK, so based on the article you linked to above, try what I said first; leave the outer single quotes around the `select`, but change the double quotes (`"`) to two single quotes (`''`). I think you've just misread what the article said (as their code wasn't monospaced). I'm not sure why that would help since it's dynamic anyway, but worth a shot I guess.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried this before, but got the error `Error(13,24): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "{" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between using || multiset member submultiset `.

Comment: @Peiqin - with **two** single quotes in place of each double quote? That error suggests you only have one... maybe you can post exactly what you have that gets that error (either in the Q or pastebin.com or somewhere).

Comment: Hi Alex, this is [the pastebin link of my code](http://pastebin.com/er2cYJfP), could you take a look? Thx.

Comment: @pequin: right, but you are only using one single quote (`'`) instead of two (`''`). I've added code to my answer; hope that's clearer.

Comment: thx, it finally works! I used two single quotes `''` instead of `"` inside `sem_match` function.